# DataBinding Issue Even after reverting back to Code Safe Point

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, android-databinding, android-build

I am using data binding in android application code. When building the code with some Data Binding issue, it gave me data binding class resolution issues. But i reverted back the code to the safe point where it was working absolutely fine. But still it keeps giving me the errors like 
"Error:(10, 53) error: cannot find symbol class ActivityForgotPasswordBinding".
It shows this error for all of my previous data binding classes. I tried so many things like
- Clear the project
- Invalidate and Restart
- Rebuilding the project
- Rebuilding the project after removing the Build Folder in the project
- Restarting the android studio
I think it is corrupting all of binding classes with some miner error with data binding class. 
Need Help.

Comment: Please include your ViewModel and your layout code. It's impossible to help you without that info. But one thing is certain: You didn't went back to a safe point.

Comment: @MartinRevert Thanks for the reply. Copy and Pasting all of my project to a new folder fixed the problem. This is weird because this is illogical. Still if i get any error in data binding then even i restore it to the safest point, it keeps giving me the data binding issues. Same solution i apply and its good to go. But i don't know why its happening like this.